# Swapping control position in TableLayoutPanel

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

EDIT:

Okay so for clarity I will improve my information a bit more:

I have a TableLayoutView (I will call this tlv) that has **5 fixed** columns, and **x + 2** rows. The first row of tlv contains labels in each cell for **header purposes**. I dynamically add more rows onto tlv and so that it why it has a variable amount of rows (plus the initial header row which is never removed).

As another tiny small complication, I also keep an empty row entry at the bottom of tlv which I must keep because I use it for other functionality.

To visualise what I have just said, this is an example of tlv consisting with 4 entries (numbered), the header row (H's) and the placeholder row (P's).

```
HHHHH
11111
22222
33333
44444
PPPPP
```

I want to go from that, to say, if I wanted to swap entry 2 and 3 the output would be:

```
HHHHH
11111
33333
22222
44444
PPPPP
```

The code I have so far is as follows:

```
for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
{
    TableLayoutPanelCellPosition tablePosition1 = new 
    TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(j, rowIndex + 1);
    Control moveControl1 = queuedFiles.GetControlFromPosition(j, rowIndex);
    queuedFiles.SetCellPosition(moveControl1, tablePosition1);

    TableLayoutPanelCellPosition tablePosition2 = new 
    TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(j, rowIndex);
    Control moveControl2 = queuedFiles.GetControlFromPosition(j, rowIndex + 1);
    queuedFiles.SetCellPosition(moveControl2, tablePosition2);

    if (j.Equals(0))
    {
        moveControl1.Text = (rowIndex + 1).ToString();
        moveControl2.Text = (rowIndex).ToString();
    }
}
```

However this code doesn't work and for the example above it produces:

```
HHHHH
11111
33222
22333
44444
PPPPP
```

What I believe is happening is tlv is automatically organising it's contents itself during the process of moving them around (maybe to fill vacant spaces?).

**rowIndex** above is the index of the target row which must be swapped with the row below it. I don't need to worry about checking if there is only 1 row or if it is the last row because I have done that already. Ignore changing the text too, I just need a pointer as to how I can achieve the intended result!

Thank you for absolutely any help you can give :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The following code does the job:**

Code

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // some content
            var panel = new TableLayoutPanel
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                ColumnCount = 5,
                RowCount = 2
            };

            for (var y = 0; y < 2; y++)
            for (var x = 0; x < 5; x++)
            {
                var control = new Button {Text = $@"X = {x}, Y = {y}"};
                panel.Controls.Add(control, x, y);
            }

            // swap button
            var button = new Button
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                Text = @"Clicky !"
            };

            button.Click += (o, args) =>
            {
                var dictionary = panel.Controls
                    .Cast<Control>()
                    .ToDictionary(k => k, v => panel.GetCellPosition(v));

                foreach (var pair in dictionary)
                {
                    var position = pair.Value;
                    position.Row ^= 1; // simple row swap
                    panel.SetCellPosition(pair.Key, position);
                }
            };

            // add to form
            var container = new SplitContainer
            {
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                SplitterWidth = 5,
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D
            };

            container.Panel1.Controls.Add(panel);
            container.Panel2.Controls.Add(button);

            Controls.Add(container);
        }
    }
}
```

Before

[image]

After

[image]

**Note**

Next time you ask a question, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to maximize your chances of getting an answer !

As on why your code didn't work, see previous sentence, e.g what was `rowIndex` etc ?

**Edit**

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            const int cols = 5;
            const int rows = 6;

            // setup layout
            var tlp = new TableLayoutPanel
            {
                ColumnCount = cols,
                RowCount = rows,
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                GrowStyle = TableLayoutPanelGrowStyle.FixedSize
            };

            for (var i = 0; i < cols; i++)
                tlp.ColumnStyles.Add(new ColumnStyle(SizeType.Percent, 100.0f / cols));

            // add header
            var label = new Label
            {
                Text = @"My Header",
                BackColor = Color.Red,
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter
            };
            tlp.Controls.Add(label);
            tlp.SetColumn(label, 0);
            tlp.SetRow(label, 0);
            tlp.SetColumnSpan(label, cols);

            // add some cells
            var yMin = 1;
            var yMax = 5;
            var xMin = 0;
            var xMax = cols;
            for (var y = yMin; y < yMax; y++)
            for (var x = xMin; x < xMax; x++)
            {
                var color = Color.FromArgb(
                    255 / (xMax - xMin) * (x - xMin),
                    128,
                    255 / (yMax - yMin) * (y - yMin)
                );
                var label1 = new Label
                {
                    Text = $@"X = {x}, Y = {y}",
                    BackColor = color,
                    ForeColor = Color.White,
                    Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
                    TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter,
                    Margin = DefaultMargin
                };
                tlp.Controls.Add(label1, x, y);
            }

            // add swapper
            var button = new Button
            {
                Text = @"Clicky !",
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            };
            button.Click += (o, args) =>
            {
                var srcRow = 2;
                var tgtRow = 3;
                var controls = tlp.Controls.Cast<Control>().ToArray();
                var array1 = controls.Where(s => tlp.GetRow(s) == srcRow).ToArray();
                var array2 = controls.Where(s => tlp.GetRow(s) == tgtRow).ToArray();

                foreach (var control in array1)
                    tlp.SetCellPosition(control, new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(tlp.GetColumn(control), tgtRow));

                foreach (var control in array2)
                    tlp.SetCellPosition(control, new TableLayoutPanelCellPosition(tlp.GetColumn(control), srcRow));
            };

            // pack things up
            var sc = new SplitContainer
            {
                Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal,
                BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Fixed3D,
                Dock = DockStyle.Fill
            };
            sc.Panel1.Controls.Add(tlp);
            sc.Panel2.Controls.Add(button);
            Controls.Add(sc);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the help! I'll give it a try now, and I'll remember to double check that post in the future!

Comment: I have tried your code, and it isn't what I intend to do but that is just my fault. I have updated my question above to see if that may make the clarity any better for you! :)

Comment: See my edit, I really don't know what's wrong on your side as here it works. Here's a tip, when some of my code refuses to work as intended, I just delete it and start over from scratch, generally I spot the error.

Comment: Thanks for all the help mate! I have finally been able to get it work with my own code but your dictionary way taught me a better way to do it so definitely thank you for all of the help! :)